# Found 0 JPA repository interfaces after I ran my spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

**1. UserRecord**

`package auj.helpdesk.model;`

> ```
> package auj.helpdesk.model;
>
> import javax.persistence.Entity;
> import javax.persistence.Id;
>
> @Entity
> public class UserRecord {
>   @Id
>   private int id;
>   private String name;
>   private String email;
>
> //default conatructor    
>   public UserRecord() {
>   }
>
>   public int getId() {
>       return id;
>   }
>
>   public void setId(int id) {
>       this.id = id;
>   }
>
>   public String getName() {
>       return name;
>   }
>
>   public void setName(String name) {
>       this.name = name;
>   }
>
>   public String getEmail() {
>       return email;
>   }
>
>   public void setEmail(String email) {
>       this.email = email;
>   }
> }
> ```

**2. UserController**

> ```
> package auj.helpdesk.controller;
>
> import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
> import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
> import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
> import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
> import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
>
> import auj.helpdesk.model.UserRecord;
> import auj.helpdesk.services.UserService;
>
> import java.util.List;
>
> @RestController
> public class UserController {
>   @Autowired
>   private UserService userService;
>
>   @RequestMapping("/")
>   public List<UserRecord> getAllUser() {
>       return userService.getAllUsers();
>   }
>
>   @RequestMapping(value = "/add-user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
>   public void addUser(@RequestBody UserRecord userRecord) {
>       userService.addUser(userRecord);
>   }
> }
> ```

**3. UserRepository**

```
package auj.helpdesk.repository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import auj.helpdesk.model.UserRecord;
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserRecord, String> {
}
```

**`4. UserService`**

```
package auj.helpdesk.services;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import auj.helpdesk.model.UserRecord;
import auj.helpdesk.repository.UserRepository;

@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public List<UserRecord> getAllUsers() {
        List<UserRecord> userRecords = new ArrayList<>();
        userRepository.findAll().forEach(userRecords::add);
        return userRecords;
    }

    public void addUser(UserRecord userRecord) {
        userRepository.save(userRecord);
    }
}
```

**AujhelpdeskApplication**

```
package auj.helpdesk.starter;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AujhelpdeskApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AujhelpdeskApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**`5. Application.properties`**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@LAPTOP-U9NGFKE9:1521:XE
spring.datasource.username=M1
spring.datasource.password=M1
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
server.port=8090
```

**`6. pom.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>auj.helpdesk</groupId>
    <artifactId>aujhelpdesk</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>aujhelpdesk</name>
    <description>A help desk for Auj</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My Spring Data repository not scanned .  I have checked my application.properties but its not working .

Comment: Can you show your application file also ? The one that contains `SpringBootApplication` annotation ?

Comment: ok i will do that, wait.

Comment: Can you update it the question body please ? Its hard to read code in comments.

Comment: I updated my body please check.

Comment: I answered your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your `AujhelpdeskApplication` is in package `auj.helpdesk.starter;`, Spring boot will only scan packages that start with `auj.helpdesk.starter`, which means it will skip `auj.helpdesk.repository` because they are siblings, `repository` does not lie inside `auj.helpdesk.starter` package.

```
package auj.helpdesk.starter;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AujhelpdeskApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AujhelpdeskApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

To address this, you either have to move your main class to package `auj.helpdesk` so that containing package is parent to all, or you have to specify locations where you want components to look into.

```
package auj.helpdesk.starter;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "auj.helpdesk")
public class AujhelpdeskApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AujhelpdeskApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try 2 solutions for this.

1. Either make your Service & Repository packages as sub packages of "auj.helpdesk.starter". Then your Service & Repository will be scanned for bean creation.
2. Or you can add @ComponentScan annotation on your main class by specifying Service & Repository packages.
   e.g. @ComponentScan({ "auj.helpdesk.repository", "auj.helpdesk.services" })

Answer (score -1):

Use `@Repository` in your UserRepository interface.

Comment: I just checked by adding @Repository but its not working yet.

Comment: Adding `@Repository` to a spring data jpa interface isn't needed and doesn't add anything.